# JavaScript works in Chrome but not ie9

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue with JavaScript.I see that it works fine in chrome but not in IE9.This would not display what chrome is displaying on the web page as expected.
I am new to JavaScripting can I get help in fixing this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                var tds = document.getElementById('course_table')
                        .getElementsByTagName('td');
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
                    if (tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
                        sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0
                                : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
                    }

                }
                var lastrecord = tds[tds.length - 2].innerHTML;

                var table = document.getElementById('course_table')
                        .getElementsByTagName('tr');
                var max = table.length - 2;
                document.getElementById('course_table').innerHTML += '<tr bgcolor=#FFCCFF><td></td><td>Total Courses</td><td>' + max + '</td><td>Total Credits Remaining</td><td>'+ sum + '</td><td> Expected Graduation Date</td><td></td><td>' + lastrecord + '</td><td></td></tr> ';
            </script>
```

Thanks
Niveditha

Comment: By not working, what do you mean?  Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: ...why is there a style attribute on your script tag?

Comment: You're JS is not valid. Start by replacing `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript..."` with `<script>`

Comment: There is no `language` `<script>` attribute, and while it won't break your code, it's not helping at all either. @Johnathan, `type` is a valid attribute for the `<script>` element.

Comment: I tried that just using <script> and also just including type attribute too but it still it doesnot work on ie9.It doesnot display what chrome would display as expected.

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't like appending `<tr>` elements to a table.

Comment: You need to explain what isn't working. Does the table show at all? How about screenshots comparing the two, or at the very least a JsFiddle?!

Comment: @rvighne Internet Explorer produces errors in the console when attempts like that are made to extend `innerHTML` of a `<table>`.

Comment: @Pointy Ah, thanks. Leave it to IE...

Comment: Have any of the answers here worked for you? Accept the one that does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely in the last line:

```
document.getElementById('course_table').innerHTML += '<tr bgcolor=#FFCCFF><td></td><td>fsffd</td><td>' + max + '</td><td>abcdRemaining</td><td>'+ sum + '</td><td> abc</td><td></td><td>' + lastrecord + '</td><td></td></tr> ';
```

IE doesn't handle `tr`s being added by strings; besides it is non-standard. Replace that line with this, it programmatically builds up the row and is faster. I added the corresponding `<td>` as comments.

```
var table = document.getElementById('course_table');
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
row.style.backgroundColor = '#FFCCFF'; // `bgcolor` attribute is deprecated

row.insertCell(-1); // <td></td>
row.insertCell(-1).textContent = "fsffd"; // <td>fsffd</td>
row.insertCell(-1).textContent = max; // <td>' + max + '</td>
row.insertCell(-1).textContent = "abcdRemaining"; // <td>abcdRemaining</td>
row.insertCell(-1).textContent = sum; // <td>' + sum + '</td>
row.insertCell(-1).textContent = "abc"; // <td> abc</td>
row.insertCell(-1); // <td></td>
row.insertCell(-1).textContent = lastRecord; // <td>' + lastRecord + '</td>
row.insertCell(-1); // <td></td>
```

The important methods here are [insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) and [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell), they are guaranteed to work. `textContent` is faster and safer than `innerHTML`. Please use CSS instead of the deprecated `bgcolor` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't like adding `<tr>` elements to the `<table>` in that manner. What you *can* do is append a new `<tbody>` element to the table:

```
// ... the first part of your function ...

var lastrecord = tds[tds.length - 2].innerHTML;

var table = document.getElementById('course_table');

var newbody = document.createElement('tbody');

newbody.innerHTML = '<tr bgcolor=#FFCCFF><td></td><td>Total Courses</td><td>' + max + '</td><td>Total Credits Remaining</td><td>'+ sum + '</td><td> Expected Graduation Date</td><td></td><td>' + lastrecord + '</td><td></td></tr> ';

table.appendChild(newbody);
```

Comment: I have tried replacing what you provided with mine, which is document.getElementById('course_table').innerHTML += '<tr bgcolor=#FFCCFF><td></td><td>Total Courses</td><td>' + max + '</td><td>Total Credits Remaining</td><td>'+ sum + '</td><td> Expected Graduation Date</td><td></td><td>' + lastrecord + '</td><td></td></tr> ';  .This still doesnot produce any effect ..please tell me if am placing it in the wrong location

Comment: please tell me how to use it...i tried as I said above ,but it doesnot  work..

Comment: You cannot use `.innerHTML += ...` in IE.  It does not work. The code I've got above should go at the end of your code. I'll add more context to the answer.